# How to train Random Forest on large datasets in python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a rather big data including 1M samples and 1K features (A 1M by 1K matrix) that I am trying to train a random forest with for a binary classification problem. Here is a code I typically use to train random forest when the data is not that large. I first read the data from a .csv file using pandas:

```
    training_all = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((100,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    training_all['Label'] = random.choices([0,1],k=100)
    test_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((20,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    test_data['Label'] = random.choices([0,1],k=20)
```

Then create a pool of hyper-parameters:

```
    # Number of trees in random forest
    n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 200, stop = 2000, num = 10)]
    # Number of features to consider at every split
    max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
    # Maximum number of levels in tree
    max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 110, num = 11)]
    max_depth.append(None)
    # Minimum number of samples required to split a node
    min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
    # Minimum number of samples required at each leaf node
    min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]
    # Method of selecting samples for training each tree
    bootstrap = [True, False]
    # Create the random grid
    hyperparameters = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
                   'max_features': max_features,
                   'max_depth': max_depth,
                   'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
                   'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
                   'bootstrap': bootstrap}
```

Then, shuffle the data:

```
    training_all_shuffled = training_all.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)  
    test_data_shuffled = test_data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And finally create and train a random forest using sklearn:

```
    randomCV = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(), param_distributions=hyperparameters, n_iter=10, cv=5,scoring="f1")
    randomCV.fit(training_all_shuffled.iloc[:,:-1], training_all_shuffled['Label'])
    best_rf_model= randomCV.best_estimator_

    rf_predictions = best_rf_model.predict(test_data_shuffled.iloc[:,:-1])
```

What are some ways to make this run in a reasonable amount of time on 1M by 1K dataset? Any tips on how to read the data (the data is also large and it'd be nice if I don't have to read it all to memory), hyper-parameters' range, parallelization and etc. is very much helpful. Thanks

Comment: You could consider using a computer cluster and SparkML (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.2/ml-guide.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GPU, you could use [cuML](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/api.html).

However, I do not know if a RandomizedSearchCV is among its features.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice using [optuna](https://optuna.org/) which is a library for hyper-parameter-optimization that is very easy to implement and can run things in [parallel](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/10_key_features/004_distributed.html) and use the GPU.